# Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object - Retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I am learning to make api calls using retrofit, But whenever i am trying to make a get request from he api My app crashes and gives the following errors..

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object
for method WeatherApi.getweatherbycity

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class java.lang.Object.
Tried:
* retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
* retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:201)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:232)
... 29 more

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow but nothing is working i am also new to mvvm and viewmodels stuffs.

class RetrofitInstance {

```
companion object{

    private val retrofit by lazy{
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val api by lazy{
        retrofit.create(WeatherApi::class.java)
    }


}
```

}

interface WeatherApi {

```
@GET("data/2.5/weather")
suspend fun getweatherbycity(
    @Query("q")
    cityname: String="London",
    @Query("appid")
    api_key: String = API_KEY
): Response<WeatherResponse>
```

}

i have created the Weather Response class using Json to kotlin converter plugin in android studio

```
data class WeatherResponse(
    val base: String,
    val clouds: Clouds,
    val cod: Int,
    val coord: Coord,
    val dt: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val main: Main,
    val name: String,
    val sys: Sys,
    val timezone: Int,
    val visibility: Int,
    val weather: List<Weather>,
    val wind: Wind
)

class WeatherRepository{

    suspend fun getweatherbycityname(cityname:String)=RetrofitInstance.api.getweatherbycity(cityname)

}

class WeatherViewModel(
    val weather_rep: WeatherRepository
):ViewModel() {

    val current_weather:MutableLiveData<Response<WeatherResponse>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getweatherbycity(city:String="London")= viewModelScope.launch {

        val weather=weather_rep.getweatherbycityname(city)
            //current_weather.postValue(weather)


    }

}
```

dependencies-

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm getting the same error

Comment: in my case, just add .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) so the exception goes away :)

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I was using `suspend` in my API interface method, however the problem was that I was using Retrofit2 2.3.0 when I should have been using Retrofit2 2.6 or higher, as according to [this](https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067), in that version they added official support for Coroutines.

My API:

```
interface CoolApi {
    @POST("/api/v1/path")
    @Headers("@: Noauth")
    suspend fun coolApiCall(@Body request: coolRequest): Response<CoolResponse>?
}
```

The Retrofit builder:

```
val api = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(createOkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(CoolApi::class.java)
```

And then I launch the Coroutine like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        val response = apiMethod(api)

        if (response!!.isSuccessful) {
            callback.onSuccess(response.code(), response.body())

        } else {
            // Error handling
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        when (e) {
            // Exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

Beware that in order to use `lifecycleScope` you need to add some dependencies. In my `gradel.build (:app)` I have:

```
    // For lifecycle-aware coroutines
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.31"
```

And then you can use `lifecycleScope` from an Activity or Fragment. If you're launching the Coroutine in another file (which was my case), you can pass it as an argument.

Comment: This was the issue in my case. It's always the little things. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly to get the response here:

```
@GET("data/2.5/weather")
suspend fun getweatherbycity(
    @Query("q")
    cityname: String="London",
    @Query("appid")
    api_key: String = API_KEY
): Response<WeatherResponse>
```

Because you're using RxJavaCallAdapterFactory please return observeable for the response

```
@GET("data/2.5/weather")
suspend fun getweatherbycity(
    @Query("q")
    cityname: String="London",
    @Query("appid")
    api_key: String = API_KEY
): Single<Response<WeatherResponse>>
```

Comment: could you try to change RxJavaCallAdapterFactory  to RxJava2CallAdapterFactory

Comment: I have tried that also but that does'nt work

Comment: it should be mark as an answer. i'm using RxJava3CallAdapterFactory as CallAdapterFactory

Answer (score 0):

interface WeatherAp make it public

Answer (score 0):

it s happened same things to me, i just updated retrofit version from build.gradle and works. try to update retrofit version.