# I'm getting an error when i use retrofit with Coroutines(Unable to create call adapter)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting an error when i make a request using retrofit library using coroutine .

```
Error -> FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.retro, PID: 31210
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object
                                                                                                        for method QuotesApi.getQuotes
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:234)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:160)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
                                                                                                        at $Proxy0.getQuotes(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        at com.example.retro.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:24)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class java.lang.Object.
                                                                                                      Tried:
                                                                                                       * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:201)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:232)
                                                                                                        ... 12 more
```

MY service File(Interface)

```
package com.example.retro
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface QuotesApi {
    @GET("quotes")
    suspend fun getQuotes(@Query("page")page:Int):Response<QuotesList>
}
```

My RetrofitHelper object file

```
package com.example.retro

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetrofitHelper {
    val BASE_URL = "https://quotable.io/"
    fun getInstance():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    }
}
```

MainActivity File

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val quotesApi = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(QuotesApi::class.java)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result = quotesApi.getQuotes(1)
        if (result != null){
            d("rty",result.body().toString())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the full error message? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66865402/unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-class-java-lang-object-retrofit) answer your question?

Comment: the same code works when i use retrofit's enque method but does not work when i use coroutine.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coroutines. I see that the error message refers to `MainActivity.kt:24`. What line is this in your code? Is it the `GlobalScope.launch`? If so, I'm guessing that's the incorrect scope to use here.

Comment: What Retrofit version are you using? That looks like the error you would get if you used a version from before they added suspend function support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working on main thread. We always use background thread when working with Api's. So, for that use:

```
     suspend fun fetchData(): String {
      return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
     // perform network request to fetch data
     val response = networkRequest()

     // parse response into a String
     val result = parseResponse(response)

     return@withContext result
   }
}
```

Where `Dispatcher.IO` works on background thread.